# Return false when element is not selected on Angular Material Table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

is it possible to return false durning an event, when none of the items in the angular table are selected ?

I have tried :

```
export1(): void {
if(this.selection.isSelected){
  this.confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?')
.subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
  if (confirmed) {
    console.log('Export successful!')
  }
});
return console.log('Select an item first!')
 }
}
```

My Select :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SELECT</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-checkbox
                   [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)"
                    color="primary">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
      if (this.selection.selected.length === 0) 
         {
           // return false; 
         }
```